# Export animated object to Ogre

Tags: animation, export

I have a .blend file which an object that I added to him some LocRotScales to animate it.

But how do I animate it in Ogre, exporting it as a .mesh is the good method ? Because I only added some LocRotScales but not more, do I need more to animate it in Ogre3D ?